# Gain root in application - Android

Tags: android, root

I have an android application which requires root access, I used the code:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes(command);
```

This works on my galaxy s3 - I see the pop-up window which asks for root access, but when I ran the applications on different devices such as "xiaomi redmi note" and "lenovo k3" the pop-up window wont come up. 
Why is that and how can I make the request show?

Comment: think, android OS framework discourages it..

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, the other phones are rooted, right?

Anyway, a bit of advice:
I'd suggest using the RootTools library for anything root-related, as it contains standarized functions.

This includes asking for root access, checking for root, executing custom root commands, etc etc. I currently use it in my own project where i turn wireless ADB on/off from a widget, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Yes there are all rooted. For example in the "xiaomi" phone, I searched the phone and found that I can give root access in the phone settings, and then my application received root access. But no pop-up.

Do you know if all rooted phone show the pop-up?

I'll try the library, Thank you.

Comment: No, there is no standard for what it means for a phone to be rooted, as this is very intentionally not a part of standard Android.

Answer (score 0):

n00b! You write:

> Yes there are all rooted. For example in the "xiaomi" phone, I
>   searched the phone and found that I can give root access in the phone
>   settings...

...phone settings? OK. But if you need to view "pop-up" you need have installed **SuperUser** and **SU binary** in /usb/bin, also you can get root acess but no pop-up will be pop-up.